# CSS background image zoomed in on mobile browsers

Tags: html, css

I have a section on my website that uses a CSS background image. The website is [here](http://www.robertsteilberg.com/). You can see where I have the fixed background image in the "Contact" section. Here is the current CSS for the image:

```
#hs-contact-section {
  color: #FFF;
  background-image: url(../images/Chapel-interior.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Interestingly, if I use a browser inspection tool to simulate a mobile-sized window, the image is zoomed correctly.

But, if I access the webpage on an actual mobile device, it looks like this:

[image: mobile screenshot]

Is there something wrong with my CSS? I've tried searching online but haven't found any solutions that have worked.

Comment: maybe your Content : #hs-contact-section  resized... remove overflow style and check again

Comment: What device are you testing on?

Comment: I'm testing on an iPhone 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more than likely because you are using a parallax effect which "does not always work on mobile devices."

refer to the note on w3schools
http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp

edit: if you want to swap our the image or disable the effect you can create a rule in your CSS

```css
//768px is generally the max mobile pixel width
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { 
    #yourId {
        element: attribute;
    }
}
```