# CSS background-image inexplicably zooming in on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, background-image

Sorry if this has been answered elsewhere; the only other place I could find this issue mentioned is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39950357/css-background-image-zoomed-in-on-mobile-browsers) but the answer given there doesn't seem relevant to my site, but I'm happy to be proven wrong.

I'm working on a site in Next.js (although I don't think the framework is relevant because this project used to be create-react-app and the same issue occurred) and our site background is a fixed starry-sky image. I'm applying that across the site by doing this in my global `app.scss` filesheet:

```
html {
    background-image: url(../public/images/background.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: black;
}
```

This works perfectly on my desktop browser – on all viewport sizes. The **first screenshot** is how the site looks when using Chrome's devtools to simulate a mobile display, after reloading the site from scratch with that viewport and everything. The **second screenshot** is when opening the site from an actual mobile device (an iPhone XS on the Chrome mobile browser). You can see that the background image is super zoomed-in:

[image] [image]

I don't know how I could inspect the styles being applied on my phone browser, so it's hard to figure out the cause of this. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: You may want to set height and width of the html tag as `html{...; width:100%; height:100%}` or `html{...; width:100vw; height:100vh}`. If you are targeting specific devices then reduce the dimensions and file size of the background image to improve load time.  Right now it looks like the image has bigger dimensions and high resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow I had missed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47909517/6867216) question, which says that `background-attachment: fixed` is unsuppored on mobile browsers. So I gave up applying the image as a background to the `html` element and instead added a `<div id="background" />` with this styling:

```
#background {
    z-index: -1;
    background-image: url(../public/images/background.jpg);
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    position: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it stretchs because of `background-size: cover;`. Depends how much you can scroll. I would change  this property: `background-repeat: repeat-y;`. Happend to me once as well.

Comment: this didn't fix it, sorry :(

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).